# Room. Сохранение объектов

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Имеется class Article, который включает в себя класс Source

```
@Entity (tableName = "article")
open class Article {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    var id: Int? = 0

    @ColumnInfo(name = "content")
    var content: String? = ""

    @ColumnInfo(name = "publishedAt")
    var publishedAt: String? = ""

    @ColumnInfo(name = "author")
    var author: String? = ""

    @ColumnInfo(name = "urlToImage")
    var urlToImage: String? = ""

    @ColumnInfo(name = "title")
    var title: String? = ""


    @TypeConverters({SourcesConverter.class})
    @ColumnInfo(name = "source")
    var sources: Sources? = null

    @ColumnInfo(name = "description")
    var description: String? = ""

    @ColumnInfo(name = "url")
    var url: String? = ""
}
```

Класс Source

```
data class Source(
        var id : String?,

        var name : String?
)
```

Необходимо написать конвертер для этого класса, чтобы Room смогла сохранить данные.

Проблема в том, что во всех примерах которые находил (например,[Ссылка 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44582397/android-room-persistent-library-typeconverter-error-of-error-cannot-figure-ou), [Ссылка 2](https://startandroid.ru/ru/27-course/architecture-components/539-urok-11-room-type-converter.html), класс представляют собой только 1 поле и его легко конвертировать между собой.

А как конвертировать классы состоящие из 2 и более полей. Какой алгоритм конвертирования?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для сохранения в качестве полей базы данных объектов (а не примитивных типов) не нужно использовать `@TypeConverter` и преобразовывать объект в JSON - для этого есть [аннотация `@Embedded`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Embedded.html), которая указывает на то, что объект нужно разложить на примитивы.

```
@Entity (tableName = "article")
open class Article {
    ...

    @Embedded
    @ColumnInfo(name = "source")
    var sources: Sources? = null
}
```

Room просто разложит этот объект на примитивы и создаст дополнительные поля в таблице с именами примитивов объекта. Если имена полей в основном Entity совпадают с именами вложенного объекта, то необходимо указать для таких полей префикс:

```
@Embedded(prefix = "source")
var sources: Sources? = null
```

В итоге будет создана таблица с полями: id, content, ... , source_id, source_name.

Заполнение такого Entity:

```
var article = Article()
article.id = 1
article.content = "Some content"
...

var source = Source()
source.id = 1
source.name = "Ivan"
article.source = source

db.dao().insert(article)
```

Embedded-классы могут быть вложены друг в друга (то есть объект `source` может так же содержать поля-объекты, которые оформляются аналогичным образом)

[подробнее](https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/architecture-components/27-course/architecture-components/530-urok-6-room-entity.html) о работе с Room Entity

PS: несущественные повторяющиеся строки заполнения полей таблицы заменены троеточием (...)

Answer (score 4):

Пример

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "source")
var sources: Sources? = null
```

описываете конвертацию из объекта в json (можно в этом же классе)

```
@TypeConverter
public String sourceToJSON(Source source) {
    return new Gson().toJson(source);
}
```

и наоборот из json в объект

```
@TypeConverter
public Source sourceFromJSON(String sourceStr) {
    Source source = new Gson().fromJson(sourceStr, Source.class);
    return source;
}
```

Не забывайте указать в главном классе DB @TypeConverters

```
@Database(entities = {Source.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(Source.class)
public abstract class DataBase extends RoomDatabase {

public abstract SourceDao getSourceDao();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой вариант: вы можете превратить ваш класс в `json` с помощью TypeConverter и наоборот.

Один метод в TypeConverter будет на создание `json` из объекта.
Второй на создание объекта из `json`.

Для создание и парсинга `json` можно использовать `Gson`