# Как конвертировать data class для ROOM

Tags: android, kotlin, entity, room, dataclass

У меня есть дата класс:

```
@Entity
data class ArticleEntity(
    val sourceEntity: SourceEntity,
    val author: String,
    val title: String,
    val description: String,
    val url: String,
    val urlToImage: String,
    val publishedAt: String,
    val content: String
) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    var id = url
}
```

И вложенный класс:

```
@Entity
data class SourceEntity(
    val id: String,
    val name: String
)
```

При компилировании ROOM выдаёт ошибку, нужно конвертировать SourceEntity.
Я искал в интернете и нашел варианты, но они в целом конвертируют один тип к другому (long на string и т.д) или конвертируют массив.
Мне нужно конвертировать этот дата класс SourceEntity в String и обратно.
Если кто в этом хорошо разбирается, прошу помочь и пояснить.

Comment: Добавьте лог ошибки в вопрос - так люди смогут его погуглить и показать вариант решения, например.

Comment: Без конкретного лога с ошибкой трудно понять зачем и во что конвертировать.

Comment: Возможно вам room намекает на type converter: https://adrianhall.github.io/android/2018/08/08/converting-types-with-room-and-kotlin/

Comment: О охранении объектов в Room [смотрите этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/884828/177345)

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение, но могут быть некие недочёты:
Создаём класс:

```
class ArticleTypeConverter {
        private val gson: Gson by lazy { Gson() }

        @TypeConverter
        fun toSource(value: String): SourceEntity {
            val arrayTutorialType = object : TypeToken<SourceEntity>() {}.type
            return gson.fromJson(value, arrayTutorialType) as SourceEntity
        }
        @TypeConverter
        fun fromSource(value: SourceEntity): String {
            return gson.toJson(value)
        }


    }
```

добавляем аннотацию в родительском датаклассе над source:Source:

```
 
@Entity
data class ArticleEntity(
    @field:TypeConverters(ArticleTypeConverter::class)
    val source: SourceEntity,
...
```

и всё заработало

Comment: очень плохое решение вы нашли, я же давал вам ссылку, как правильно делать через аннотацию @Embedded, к чему плодить такие сложности, подключать дополнительные и не маленькие библиотеки, хранить какие то промежуточные форматы  json, тратить время и ресурсы устройства на все эти преобразования, когда данные должны считываться максимально быстро, если есть простое, быстрое и правильное решение?

Comment: К тому же такой подход делает невозможной (как минимум очень сложной) выборку с условием по содержимому полей `SourceEntity`